# iOS P2P library integration giving error /string.h: Use of undeclared identifier 'strlen'

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, p2p, rtsp

I am trying to integrate P2P library in iOS code, It contain low level libraries and class files. 
I have properly set the path of all libraries and header files in Build Settings. 
Now when i build the library i am getting the following error:

```
/pjlib/include/pj/string.h:94:33: Use of undeclared identifier 'strlen'
/pjlib/include/pj/string.h:473:20: Use of undeclared identifier 'memchr'
/pjlib/include/pj/string.h:616:5: Use of undeclared identifier 'memset'
```

Also it gave error to Math function:
    /External/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIAuthenticationDialog.m:156:83: Use of undeclared identifier 'M_PI'

Please give me some idea what should be the problem... i am giving snapshot link of my build settings.

[image: Headers under Build Settings]
[image: Library Search Path]